# Blocking unarmed

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've got a question about the Khajiit's unarmed attacking ability. Somehow, and I don't know how, I was able to attack unarmed one-handed, attacking with the right hand while being able to block with the left hand. It surprised the heck out of me, because I didn't know I could do it. When he blocked, he closed his left hand over his right fist and took the block with his forearm, I guess. Right now, he is wearing steal guantlets, but I don't know if that matters. What that a happy glitch that will never happen again, or is there a way I can get that back, because that totally rocked!

Comment: If there was a separate animation I'd be surprised if it was a glitch, unless it happened to be two of the usual animations overlapping somehow. Haven't heard about unarmed blocking, though.

Comment: Do you mean with your bare hands? Or a weapon

Answer (score 3):

According to [the UESP wiki](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Block),

> If **nothing**, a shield or a torch is equipped in the left hand, or if a two-handed weapon is equipped, incoming attacks can be blocked by holding the Left Hand (block) control. *[emphasis mine]*

And the [Elder Scrolls wiki](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Block_%28Skyrim%29) says

> Block with one-handed weapons is also possible if left hand stays unoccupied. [sic]

While this second reference may imply you need a weapon in your right hand to block, I think the emphasis is on the second part of the sentence - *if left hand stays unoccupied*.

So it looks like you can block while unarmed after all!

Comment: Eh? But how did I do it? It's funny, because while fighting a falmer, somehow he lost his weapon and was doing the unarmed blocking thing to block me, so I was like, see? He's doing it? How did I do it? I'm not crazy after all!

Comment: @Stan that first quote says you can block "by holding the Left Hand (block) control." Tried that?

Comment: If both hands are unarmed, then the normal behavior for Left Hand button is left hand punch, not block. This is an interesting glitch. I'll try to duplicate this, but I have never seen or heard about this before.

Answer (score 3):

I found out how to do this glitch - just go to a torch and block while unarmed, then unequip torch and you're blocking. You do have to hold block.

Answer (score 1):

I recently came across this glitch & while experimenting found out how to do it. I was a vampire with vampiric drain equipped in the left hand. I saved & went onto a different game where I wasn't a vampire. When I went back to my first game vampiric drain was not equipped but the hand was held open in fp view. I could then block with my left hand. Did this several times, it worked consistently but the blacking animation is the same as blocking with a dagger

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Dual Wield Parrying](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/9247) mod to block while dual-wielding, unarmed or with a spell in your left hand.